# Is there a way to produce random numbers simultaneously in c++? If not, is there a work around?

Tags: c++

```
class Class{
  int produceRandom(){
    int ranNum = rand() % 5;
    //other unrelated code
    return ranNum;
}

std::vector<Class> classes;

int main(){
  srand(time(NULL));
  //codey code, unrelated

  if (classes.empty() == false){
    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++){
      //Code produces a number of classes if certain conditions are met
      int useRanNum = classes[i].produceRandom();
    }
  }
}
```

The numbers are random enough for each iteration through the code, but each classes produces the same number for each iteration.

I've hit a complete block here and it's driving me insane. Is their a work around? Am I doing something wrong? I've tried using a Mersenne Twister, but to the same result. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please check this link : https://medium.com/@sourav39.csesust/random-number-generation-in-c-c-without-library-function-d031ccab201d

Comment: Please change the shown code to demonstrate "each classes produces the same number for each iteration". I.e. please provide a [mre].

Comment: *cough cough* `i` is unintialized *cough cough*

Comment: Watch that *cough*, there is a bad bug going around.... (yes, pun intended)

Comment: For all we know, the OP could be coding a virus.

Comment: *"simultaneously"* makes think about threading which is indeed problematic with some generator as `random`. But in single thread, it is not problematic.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed if you use the random library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class Class{
private:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
public:
  Class() : rd(), mt(rd()), dist(0, 100) {}

  int produceRandom() {
    return dist(mt);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Class r;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
      std::cout << r.produceRandom() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I get the following error implementing this: "class::class(const class&) use of deleted function"

Comment: I commented out the //random_device line, and then it works, but I still get the same problem from before.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible bugs:

This line:

```
for (int i; i < classes.size(); i++){
```

`i` is uninitialized.  Hence undefined behavior and/or consistently weird results.   Should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++){
```

Also, no point in checking `classes.empty() == false`, the corrected loop initialization will do that for you.

But my psychic powers suggest there's another call to `srand(N)` lurking in the code or Where `N` is some constant value.  Quite possibly in the section of code you aren't showing yet, and/or a library you are calling into.

A possible fix is to move the `srand(time(NULL))` call after "codey code, unrelated" and before the loop.

That is:

```
int main(){
  //codey code, unrelated


  srand(time(NULL));  // move this line to be directly before the loop.

  if (classes.empty() == false){
    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++){
      //Code produces a number of classes if certain conditions are met
      int useRanNum = classes[i].produceRandom();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: int i not being initialized is irrelevant. This was just code I typed out quickly, rather than copy pasting. But thanks for the tip for removing the "if" statement.

Comment: @RiverreedWard -- the error in the code is not irrelevant. The code you showed will, at best, produce nonsense, so asking people to reason about why it doesn't produce the result you expect is pointless.

Comment: @PeteBecker it most certainly is irrelevant, because that bug is not present in the code of the program. It is only present here because I typed out the basic idea of the program.

Comment: @RiverreedWard -- the code you **posted** does not demonstrate the problem that your question asks about. The fact that you meant to post **some other code** doesn't change that.

Comment: @RiverreedWard - Pete is correct. When you post pseudo code that doesn't actually reproduce the issue you are inquiring about, the only thing we can do is speculate and guess. Or in my case, fallback to my psychic powers.   I stand by my answer - that `srand` is getting invoked somewhere else in your program unbeknownst to you.  But that's just a guess given that you haven't actually produced a [mcve]